# How to prevent user from modifying REST request?

Tags: node.js, rest

This question might sound trivial, but even after reading a number of tutorials, I still don't get how the REST security should be implemented.

I have a webpage and soon-to-be-ready mobile app. Both of them will be using the REST API (written in node.js), and the question is - how can I prevent users from modyfing those requests? It's very easy to see the network traffic in the browser, and all the GET/POST requests that are made to the server. It also seems very easy to copy such a request, modify its parameters and/or payload and send it to the server.

How do I make sure that's my webpage or the app who made the request, and not someone else?

Comment: from personal experience i would say to do small checks and preventive measures server-side.  I'm assuming you're trying to avoid floods and injections, etc?  You can try checking the Content-Length header and if it's too large (larger than expecting), drop and send back an error.  If it passes, send it through a sanitizer to remove any attempts at injected code.  Nothing is fool-proof in security, you can only mitigate your risk by covering known weaknesses.  PS - I don't know much about how the requests are handled at a low level but I believe cross-origin restrictions should prevent this.

Comment: Pretty much, you can't.  Anything your server exposes can be used by any client on the internet.  Anything your own Javascript in a web page does can be used by any script anywhere.  Require an account and authentication for that account and then you can disable the accounts of any significant abusers that are harming the system.  But you can't prevent others from using your API.  You get more protection if you keep more functionality in the server, exposing only interface elements from the server, but that has other drawbacks.

Comment: Q: How do I make sure that's my webpage or the app who made the request, and not someone else?  A: There are *LOTS* of alternatives.  Start by looking at the [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet) referenced below.  For example: "Anti-replay: Consider using a time limited encryption key, keyed against the session token or API key, date and time, and incoming IP address....".  No single technique is *guaranteed*, but you *CAN* mitigate the risks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sisyphus is absolutely correct: your focus should be on securing the channel (TLS, SSH, etc) and authentication (e.g. OAuth2).

You should absolutely familiarize yourself with the [Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OWASP).  In particular, start with:

- [OWASP Top 10 Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet)
- [OWASP REST Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Here is an excellent "hands on" tutorial that gives you a great overview of all the different pieces you need to worry about:

- [Authenticate a Node.js API with JSON Web Tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

Once you've gone through the tutorial and scanned the OWASP cheat sheets, you'll have a much better idea of what kinds of things you need to worry about, what options/technologies are available to mitigate those risks, and what might work best for your particular scenario.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Typically, security these days uses a combination of Transport Layer Security and OAuth2. OAuth2 provides authentication and authorisation, ensuring appropriate access to resources, with TLS both securing data over the network and preventing the kind of replay attacks which you're concerned about. Neither are really specific to Restful APIs and you can find them being used in non-Rest contexts also.